# Can I use events with the REST api of Firebase?

Tags: python, firebase

with the JS api of Firebase I can use various events. (Value; Child Added; Child Changed; Child Removed; Child Moved.)

I would like to have callbacks to the same events somehow from Python. The Python api uses the REST API of Firebase. So, it is possible to detect if a child has changed / added / etc.. in a collection, via REST?

Comment: It looks like you might be able to use the JS callback available to GETs to inject an event listener, but you'd have to implement some sort of server on the client to receive the messages sent when the listeners are fired.  It sounds like you basically want to subscribe to assets from a Python client, but the REST API is really focused on handling individual transactions, so you'll have to modify it or find some way to subvert it to your ends.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third-party, limited port of the JS API to Python:  https://github.com/abeisgreat/python-firebasin

So you can get some limited event functionality, excluding queries and other advanced features, via this approach.

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you. I will keep on eye on this. - Why is the limitation, is there a reason for that, or maybe this could be worked to a full api?

Comment: The real time interactions are very complex and this sort of lib isn't documented or supported by the team yet. Thus the limited.