# How does REST API's callback in firebase work?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, firebase

I am using firebase REST APIs to create a windows phone 8 app which uses C# as a programming language. Firebase reads data through 5 different event types callbacks namely Value, Child Added, Child Changed, Child Removed and Child Moved (https://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html)

How to use these event handler callbacks in REST API query parameter **callback**? It says use to use GET method for https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/fred/name/first.json?callback=gotData

But what are the function parameters of gotData? How to recognize if it is Value that has changed or Child Added or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to receive events using the REST api. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366187/can-i-use-events-with-the-rest-api-of-firebase) question. Looks like yours although the language is Python instead of C#.

The callback parameter isn't a callback as you might expect. It is used to wrap the JSON in a function. This is called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides event stream on data changes. Just put "Accept:text/event-stream" to your https request.  **ex) curl -k -H "Accept:text/event-stream" https://sampleapp.firebaseio.com/test.json -L**